# How to convert tensorflow model (InceptionResnetV2 pb file) to pytorch model using mmconvert?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

```
Platform : ubuntu 16.04
Python version: 3.5.2
mmdnn version : 0.2.5
Source framework with version : Tensorflow 1.14.0 with GPU
Destination framework with version : Pytorch 1.1.0
```

**Pre-trained model path :**

inception resnet v2 model(tensorflow)
(from https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim)

**Running scripts:**

```
mmconvert -sf tensorflow -iw inception_resnet_v2_jsy.pb --inNodeName input --inputShape 299,299,3 --dstNodeName InceptionResnetV2/Logits/Logits/BiasAdd -df pytorch -om tf_to_pytorch_inception_resnet_v2.pth
```

Hello,

I'm tried to convert tensorflow model (pb file of inception resnet v2 ) to pytorch model for using mmdnn.

I got successful results for 2 models with pb files (resnet_v1_50, inception_v3) , but when I tried to convert inception_resnet_v2, I got below errors.

Is there anyone who have some ideas to solve them or to explain those problems?

```
Error logs.


IR network structure is saved as [09db48a5839944eeb4492ee2a0959097.json].
IR network structure is saved as [09db48a5839944eeb4492ee2a0959097.pb].
IR weights are saved as [09db48a5839944eeb4492ee2a0959097.npy].
Parse file [09db48a5839944eeb4492ee2a0959097.pb] with binary format successfully.
Target network code snippet is saved as [tf_to_pytorch_inception_resnet_v2.py].
Target weights are saved as [09db48a5839944eeb4492ee2a0959097.npy].
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/mmconvert", line 11, in 
sys.exit(_main())
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/mmdnn/conversion/_script/convert.py", line 112, in _main
dump_code(args.dstFramework, network_filename + '.py', temp_filename + '.npy', args.outputModel, args.dump_tag)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/mmdnn/conversion/_script/dump_code.py", line 32, in dump_code
save_model(MainModel, network_filepath, weight_filepath, dump_filepath)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/mmdnn/conversion/pytorch/saver.py", line 5, in save_model
model = MainModel.KitModel(weight_filepath)
File "tf_to_pytorch_inception_resnet_v2.py", line 476, in init
self.InceptionResnetV2_Logits_Logits_MatMul = self.__dense(name = 'InceptionResnetV2/Logits/Logits/MatMul', in_features = -1, out_features = 1001, bias = True)
File "tf_to_pytorch_inception_resnet_v2.py", line 1444, in __dense
layer = nn.Linear(**kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/linear.py", line 76, in init
self.weight = Parameter(torch.Tensor(out_features, in_features))

RuntimeError: Trying to create tensor with negative dimension -1: [1001, -1]
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead `mmconvert` you can use the [tf2onnx](https://github.com/onnx/tensorflow-onnx) package to convert Tensorflow to ONNX. Then you can load the `.onnx` model and save it as `.pth`.

Comment: hi. How do you load an onnx model and save as .pth? All the tutorials I found talk about how to save pth as onnx